# ESP - measure time between two inputs in high speed

Tags: digital-logic, input, esp32

I have a ESP32, and have 4 digital signals. At the beginning all 4 are low, and as soon as any one of those goes high, the other 3 follow up. I would need to measure the time between the first one and the other three.. The problem is that the time delta is very small. The other input should be high between `0.0003 ms` and `0.023 ms`. I am trying to measure the time sound takes to travel inside a 15 cm steel plate (about 3150m/s).

Is there any way (also with cheap external components) to measure such tiny intervals?

Comment: How much resolution/accuracy do you require?

Comment: @DaveTweed at least 1mm, hence the 0.0003ms..

Comment: 300ns. The RMT module should be able to do that easily.

Comment: thank you, should I keep polling the inputs and measure the time? or how would it be done with the RMT module?

Comment: @sharkyenergy By my computations, \$\frac{15 \:\text{cm}}{3150 \frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}}\approx 48\:\mu\text{s}\$. And \$1\:\text{mm}\$ resolution does say about \$320\:\text{ns}\$. Which I'd cut in half to create a design goal. So I'd use \$150\:\text{ns}\$. In addition, digital inputs to any MCU have a sampling uncertainty to them, relative to clocking. I'd be zeroed in on the specs there. (Haven't looked. Just putting it on top of the table in plain view.) Anyone disagree so far?

Comment: @jonk , thank you. Not being english my main language I am not sure I understand exactly what you are trying to say. we agree on the 320, (hence my 0.0003 ms) and I agree on the 150us for safety. but the rest? are you implying that it wont work or that it works? thank you for your time!

Comment: Without having the time to read the docs: Is it possible for the ESP32 to latch a fast running timer (150ns -> ~ 7MHz) on edges on input pins? Several microcontroller can do this, even with multiple pins, each to another latch, and raising an interrupt flag at the same time. Your program can wait until "enough" flags are set, and then read the latches to calculate the intervals.